# ROS2 convert STEP to urdf

Tags: ros2, urdf, ros-humble, collada, universal-robot

For my bachelor project I have to be able to remote control a ur10e robot with gripper in VR. The robot has an adaptive plate attached to its flange, so that it can hold a camera and the gripper. For the VR simulation I use unity and the urdf importer plugin.
I could generate the urdf files for the robot and gripper but I only have a [STEP](https://robotiq.com/products/2f85-140-adaptive-robot-gripper)(Download files-> Universal Robots-> Mounting CAD-> Coupling and adapter plates) file of the connection piece.

Through previous forum posts I have found out to convert the STEP in dae and stl files and include them in a xacro file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="adapter">

  <link name="world"/>
  <link name="adapter">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/urdf/plate/meshes/Gripper_Adapter.dae" scale="1 1 1"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.05"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ur_description/urdf/plate/meshes/Gripper_Adapter.stl" scale="1 1 1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
</robot>
```

But when I try to transform this xacro to a urdf with the command:

```
ros2 run xacro xacro $(ros2 pkg prefix ur_description)/share/ur_description/urdf/plate/adapter.urdf.xacro \
name:=adapter > adapter.urdf
```

It fails.
Could anyone please give me some advice? I would appreciate it!

Comment: What means it fails? Could you please add the error/console output?

Comment: After rebooting my PC it suddenly worked and I could generate the urdf. I am sorry but I can't remember the error output.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you miss the joints between links, every link needs a joint connection it to another link (can be fixed to the the world).

Beside that, if you want a functional gripper for simulation this setup won't work either. For a functional gripper you need to have a link for both fingers with a joint so you can control the joint with a movegroup. I would suggest taking a look into the panda arm and how the gripper is defined there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I figured that I would need three joints to connect the adapter to the arm, camera and gripper. But I was not sure how it works in relation with the model. When I specify those joints how do I tell they are at the right position of the model?

I was thinking of creating a complete urdf then use the moveit setup assistance to generate the msg files so that I can use it in unity